# Embedding cache aligned meta data inside mbuf

Tags: dpdk

I'm developing my own dpdk application and I wish received packets to go through several threads in series. Each individual thread has it's own duty of inspecting packets and generating some metadata for each individual packet. It appears to be the easiest and most efficient way to transfer packets between threads is using rte rings. However I need to transfer the metadata generated by each thread to the next thread as well. I have tried doing this using array of structures for metadata and parsing a pointer to next thread. However this method proved to be inefficient since I got lot of cache misses.

As a solution I came up with idea of putting metadata generated by each thread into mbufs themselves. It seems to be doable with "Dynamic fields" of mbufs. However documentation of this feature seems to be very limited. For my application I wish to use a metadata field inside dynamic field something like this,

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t packet_id;
    uint64_t time_stamp;
    uint8_t ip_v;
    uint32_t length;
    .........
    .........
} my_metadata_field;
```

What I don't understand is how much space I can use for dynamic field? The only thing mentioned about this on dpdk documentation is,

> "10.6.1. Dynamic fields and flags
>
> The size of the mbuf is constrained and limited; while the amount of
> metadata to save for each packet is quite unlimited. The most basic
> networking information already find their place in the existing mbuf
> fields and flags.
>
> If new features need to be added, the new fields and flags should fit
> in the “dynamic space”, by registering some room in the mbuf
> structure:
>
> dynamic field -
> named area in the mbuf structure, with a given size (at least 1 byte) and alignment constraint."

which doesn't make much sense for me. How much memory I have for this field? If it's almost unlimited, what are the tradeoffs I have to deal with if I use a large metadata field? (performance wise)

I use dpdk 20.08

**Edit:**

After some digging I have abandoned the idea of using dynamic field for metadata since lack of documentation and it doesn't appears to be able to hold more than 64bits.
I am looking for an easy way to embed my metadata inside cache aligned mbufs (preferably using a struct like above) so I can use rte rings to share them between threads. I'm looking for any documentation or reference project for me to begin with.

Comment: You tagged your question with both **C** and **C++** tags. Those are two different languages. 
 Please edit your question to remove the tag that you don't use.

Comment: current question is about DPDK API usage and not mutli-threading, removing the tag multi-thread

Comment: @VipinVarghese thanks for correction. Any idea about dynamic field? I did some more digging on pktgen source and couple of mail archives and it seems to be this field is limited to 64bits (but I'm not exactly sure).  Any idea how else I can efficiently transfer packets with metadata between threads?

Comment: @Anuradha there are a lot of simpler ways to embed cache aligned meta data in mbuf. But since you are exploring dynamic-metadata field , I will wait for your exploration, let you exploration. If you are still stuck can suggest easy way out as the answer.

Comment: @VipinVarghese After some more exploring,I have concluded dynamic field isn't ideal for my requirements. Really appreciate if you could explain an easier method to embed cache aligned meta data in mbuf as an answer. My goal is to embed a custom metadata field  on mbufs so I would have least amount of cache misses. thanks.

Comment: @Anuradha can you please update the ticket for the real request.

Comment: @VipinVarghese I have updated my request, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to carry metadata along with MBUF. Following are the options to do the same

1. in function `rte_mempool_create` instead of passing *private_data_size* as 0 pass the size as `custom metadata size`.
2. in function `rte_pktmbuf_pool_create` instead of passing *priv_size* as 0 pass the size as `custom metadata size`
3. if size of metadata is less than 128 Bytes, use typecast to access memory area right after rte_mbuf
4. If there are no external buffer used in DPDK application, update rte_mbuf `shinfo or next`

Solution 1: `rte_mempool_create("FIPS_SESS_PRIV_MEMPOOL", 16, sess_sz, 0, sizeof(my_metadata_field), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, rte_socket_id(), 0);`

Solution 2: `rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("MBUF_POOL", NUM_MBUFS * nb_ports, MBUF_CACHE_SIZE, sizeof(my_metadata_field), RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, rte_socket_id());`

Solution 3:

```
struct rte_mbuf *bufs[BURST_SIZE];
const uint16_t nb_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst(port, 0, bufs, BURST_SIZE);

if (unlikely(nb_rx == 0))
    continue;
    
for (int index = 0; index < nb_rx; index++)
{
    assert(sizeof(my_metadata_field) <= RTE_CACHE_LINE_SIZE);
    my_metadata_field *ptr = bufs[index] + 1;
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Solution 4:

```
privdata_ptr = rte_mempool_create("METADATA_POOL", 16 * 1024, sizeof(my_metadata_field), 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, rte_socket_id(), 0);

struct rte_mbuf *bufs[BURST_SIZE];
const uint16_t nb_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst(port, 0, bufs, BURST_SIZE);

if (unlikely(nb_rx == 0))
    continue;
    
for (int index = 0; index < nb_rx; index++)
{
    void *msg = NULL;
    if (0 == rte_mempool_get(privdata_ptr, &msg))
    {
         assert(msg != NULL);
         bufs[index]->shinfo = msg;
         continue;
    }

    /* free the mbuf as we are not able to retrieve the private data */
}

/* before transmit or pkt free ensure to release object back to mempool  via rte_mempool_put */
```

Comment: Perfect answer and well explained! This is exactly what I wanted to do. Going to test right away. Thank you very much!

Comment: sorry for late catch on. It looks like bufs[index]->shinfo = msg; in 4th method is invalid. I get `invalid conversion from void* to rte_mbuf_ext_shared_info`. Casting msg to rte_mbuf_ext_shared_info * didn't help either since it compiled but my metadata wasn't there. Any ideas how can I continue?

Comment: @Anuradha as mentioned in solution 4 one has to use `shinfo or next` pointer to hold the location of your custom data. if DPDK 20.08 does not have `shinfo` one should use `next` pointer. I am not sure what you are trying to do with ` bufs[index]->shinfo = msg` Is msg a pointer or actual struct element? You are aware how to reach on skype. Keep you sample code ready and call me on skype

Comment: @Anuradha I have been waiting for your call to debug the issue you mentioned yesterday, So far I have not received any updates or reply. Looks like you were able to figure out what was wrong so best wishes for your work.

Comment: Sorry for keeping you waiting. I had some other urgent task to complete. I still wansn't able to implement this on my application. I'll contact you on skype. Sorry for trouble.